# why does the site display strangely? HTML + CSS

Tags: html, css

The url to the site is http://server6.stredwicks.co.uk/facilities.html

The problem is the massive block of colour that shouldn't be there. and the footer gets messed up.

Any help would be appreciated.

The problem lies in the footer which is the same code as http://server6.stredwicks.co.uk

Thanks

Comment: I think you hav some unclosed divs

Comment: please specify which block of color are you refering to please...

Comment: [Validate your site then see if the problem persists](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fserver6.stredwicks.co.uk%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add: `overflow: auto;` to: `#container` in: `layout.css` on line 244

This is needed because in the given example #container has no height due to all it's children being floated.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have wrong construction of wrappers (different HTML tree), comparing to the original code. 
I think there is something wrong with not closed correctly html tags. Use firebug (firefox extension) to find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As maugur said there some `unclosed` elements

like this one in inside the `class="subnav"`

```
<li><a href="#">Other Attractions</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Open Farm</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Wedding Venue</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Farm Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Craft Hall</a></li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
```